# Why "An HTML editor" not "A HTML editor"?

Tags: abbreviations

I always see `An HTML editor` but surely it would be `A HTML editor` as the H isn't a vowel nor does it sound like a vowel.

Why is this?

Comment: because we often write as we speak, with *h* being pronounced as /eɪtʃ/, that is, sounding like a vowel. We use *an* before a word starting with a vowel. *a fruit*, *an apple*.

Comment: Code is uncountable. It's always neither of those.

Comment: Fixed it for you :) but missed the duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Not if you pronounce H as *aitch* **/ˈeɪtʃ/**

Aussies may pronounce it as the Irish which seems to be *haitch* which may make more sense than not

The An/Thee vs A/The has to do with pronunciation/sound, not spelling

Other examples

A eunuch, an hour

It comes down to avoiding vowel/vowel *sound* clash

http://www.abc.net.au/wordmap/rel_stories/aitch.htm

> Any child learning the alphabet understands that ***a*** is for ***apple*** and ***b*** is for ***bat***. This is a good starting point for capturing the sound of letters, although already quite a lot has been glossed over in the creation of letter-to-sound equivalences. It is intuitively more logical to relate the name of the letter ***h*** to the aspirated rather than the unaspirated form. That is to say, ***h*** is for ***hat*** rather than ***hour***. "***Haitch*** is for ***hat***", the child says. "No! No! No!," we all yell. "You must never, never say ***haitch***. ***Aitch*** is for ***hat***". It doesn’t add up but the parental pain is evident so the children add that to the list of extraordinary and pointless things they are supposed to say and do while their parents are around.